# inline-block links don't work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

I'm running into a bug in Microsoft Edge where `<a>` tags are unclickable. I've managed to distill it to the simplest example here:

```css
a {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

a::after {
  visibility: visible;
  content: "more";
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">go!</a>
</span>
```

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Ideas? Sure, don't make it invisible. But that's not what you meant right? Seriously now, what is the problem you're trying to solve? I'm guessing you're unable to change the HTML, so you want to use CSS to change the link text?

Comment: Correct, cannot change the html. The content needs to be replaced in the ::after pseudo-class and the styling for the original `<a>` needs to be hidden.

Comment: @johnnysnel I'm curious, why can't you change the markup? Shimming content away in the `::after` element, and *hiding* the primary element, can't be good for accessibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm using IE11 here, but it has the same problem you describe for Edge, so I hope this solution will work there too.
It's a bit of a hack though; if better solutions come up, I'll gladly delete this one.

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow:visible;
  color:white; /* note: use current background color */
  position:relative;
}

a::after {
  color:black; /* note: use current foregound color */
  content: "more";
  position:absolute; left:0; top:0;
}
```

```html
<span>
  <a href="#">go!</a>
</span>
```

Comment: nice, thanks! Not pretty but it works. I replaced `color: white` with `color: transparent` is the only difference.

Comment: You're welcome. I never even though about trying `transparent`. If that works, so much the better!